# Parsing content of an uploaded file in POST method

Tags: html, c, cgi

How can I remove the unnecessary parts of an uploaded file content? I am using an HTML form file upload to get the file. But after submitting the file and using **CONTENT_LENGTH** , it seems to have extra information displayed like "WebKitBoundary[random characters]"". How can I remove those headers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `fgets` in a `while` loop until it reads all of the input from `stdin`. Then, I loaded them in a *buffer*, remove those unnecessary strings by setting them to `NULL`.